# javascript to update Joomla text field on page load

Tags: javascript, joomla

When a page loads, I need to add the current date in this format (mm/dd/yyy) into a Joomla form field using javascript. (the form extension does not have ability to do this) The field ID=938.

I tried using this code, but it is not working in Joomla so I assume there's a special code:

```
<script>
   document.getElementById('938').value = (new Date()).format("mm/dd/yyyy");
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why you are using JavaScript as there is option available in joomla form itself.

Comment: What form extension? If you are using an extension you need to ask the extension developer.

Comment: there is NOT an option to do this in the form (JSN Uniform). The authors are considering it as an option in the future but for now I can use Sourcerer and get the job done, but I need the Joomla equivalent to make it work.  thanks

Comment: Well if you use jform you can use a default or preset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSN Uniform does not provide any option to display current date on field, so you can try following code.

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){
    dd="0"+dd
} 
if(mm<10){
    mm="0"+mm
} 
var today = mm+"/"+dd+"/"+yyyy;             
document.getElementById('938').value = today;
```